# Using PHP's foreach to create array of values from JSON data

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm working with JSON data for the first time and I've got some PHP to grab some JSON data like below (except there are hundreds of **measuregrps** within **body**).

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://wbsapi.withings.net/measure?action=getmeasures");
$json_o = json_decode($json);
```

How do I use foreach to, say, create a 1-dimensional array of values for type = 1?

```
    {
        "status": 0,
        "body": {
            "updatetime": 1249409679,
            "measuregrps": [
                {
                    "grpid": 2909,
                    "attrib": 0,
                    "date": 1222930968,
                    "category": 1,
                    "measures": [
                        {
                            "value": 79300,
                            "type": 1,
                            "unit": -3
                        },
                        {
                            "value": 652,
                            "type": 5,
                            "unit": -1
                        },
                        {
                            "value": 178,
                            "type": 6,
                            "unit": -1
                        },
                        {
                            "value": 14125,
                            "type": 8,
                            "unit": -3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "grpid": 2908,
                    "attrib": 0,
                    "date": 1222930968,
                    "category": 1,
                    "measures": [
                        {
                            "value": 78010,
                            "type": 1,
                            "unit": -3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "grpid": 2907,
                    "attrib": 0,
                    "date": 1222930968,
                    "category": 1,
                    "measures": [
                        {
                            "value": 77300,
                            "type": 1,
                            "unit": -3
                        },
                        {
                            "value": 678,
                            "type": 5,
                            "unit": -1
                        }

                    ]
                },


            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes one's goal is clearer to the person asking than the person reading. What, exactly, should the output be? `array(/* ... */)` notation would be especially helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$values = array();

foreach($json_o->body->measuregrps as $group){
  foreach($group->measures as $measure){
    if($measure->type == 1){
      $values[] = $measure->value;
    }
  }
}

print_r($values);
```

will do

Answer (score 2):

```
$json_o = json_decode($json,true);

$result = array();

foreach ($json_o['body']['measuregrps'] as $measuregrp)
 foreach ($measuregrp['measures'] as $measure)
  if ($measure['type'] == 1)
   $result []= $measure['value'];
```

Comment: But next time please try to come up with some code yourself, then we can help if it doesn't work.

Comment: This actually won't work, as `body` etc. are instances of stdClass. They are not arrays, so they cannot be called as arrays.

Comment: It does work, since the second parameter says that the result should use associative arrays instead of standard objects. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I hate heinous mixtures of objects and arrays in PHP, so I always call JSON decode like that.